# Huge performance drop in cassandra-orm after million records

Tags: grails, cassandra, cassandra-jdbc

I'm using cassandra-orm plugin ([cassandra-orm:0.4.5](https://grails.org/plugin/cassandra-orm)) for migrating clicks from Postgres DB to Cassandra. (I know I could use raw data import, but I want to make use of groupBy and explicit indexes maintained by the plugin).

The migration procedure is simple: I select a bunch of clicks from Postgres (via GORM) and then I flush them to Cassandra. Every click is a new record and a new object is created in Grails and saved in Cassandra. With 20 threads I was able to reach throughput of 2000 clicks/sec. **After importing 5 mil clicks the performance started to degrade dramatically to 50 clicks/sec.**

I made some profiling and I've found out, that 19 threads were waiting (parked) and one thread was performing a rehash on Groovy's AbstractConcurrentMapBase.

stack trace for waiting threads:

```
Name: pool-4-thread-2
State: WAITING on org.codehaus.groovy.util.ManagedConcurrentMap$Segment@5387f7af
Total blocked: 45,027  Total waited: 55,891

Stack trace: 
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:811)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:842)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1178)
org.codehaus.groovy.util.LockableObject.lock(LockableObject.java:34)
org.codehaus.groovy.util.AbstractConcurrentMap$Segment.put(AbstractConcurrentMap.java:101)
org.codehaus.groovy.util.AbstractConcurrentMap$Segment.getOrPut(AbstractConcurrentMap.java:97)
org.codehaus.groovy.util.AbstractConcurrentMap.getOrPut(AbstractConcurrentMap.java:35)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ThreadManagedMetaBeanProperty$ThreadBoundGetter.invoke(ThreadManagedMetaBeanProperty.java:180)
groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1604)
groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1140)
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3332)
groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1152)
com.nosql.Click.getProperty(Click.groovy)
```

stack trace for rehash thread:

```
Name: pool-4-thread-11
State: RUNNABLE
Total blocked: 46,544  Total waited: 57,433

Stack trace: 
 org.codehaus.groovy.util.AbstractConcurrentMapBase$Segment.rehash(AbstractConcurrentMapBase.java:217)
org.codehaus.groovy.util.AbstractConcurrentMap$Segment.put(AbstractConcurrentMap.java:105)
org.codehaus.groovy.util.AbstractConcurrentMap$Segment.getOrPut(AbstractConcurrentMap.java:97)
org.codehaus.groovy.util.AbstractConcurrentMap.getOrPut(AbstractConcurrentMap.java:35)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ThreadManagedMetaBeanProperty$ThreadBoundGetter.invoke(ThreadManagedMetaBeanProperty.java:180)
groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1604)
groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1140)
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3332)
groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1152)
com.fma.nosql.Click.getProperty(Click.groovy)
```

After hours of debugging I've found out, that the issue is in dynamic property "_cassandra_cluster_" which is added to all plugin managed objects:

```
// cluster property (_cassandra_cluster_)
clazz.metaClass."${CLUSTER_PROP}" = null
```

This property is then internally saved in [ThreadManagedMetaBeanProperty](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.3.1/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/metaclass/ThreadManagedMetaBeanProperty.java#ThreadManagedMetaBeanProperty) instance2Prop map. When the dynamic property is accessed `def cluster = click._cassandra_cluster_` then the click instance is saved to instance2Prop map with soft reference. So far so good, soft references can be garbage collected, right. However there seems to be a bug in the ManagedConcurrentMap implementation which disregards the garbage collected elements and keep rehashing and expanding the map (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593191/bug-in-groovy-abstractconcurrentmap?noredirect=1) and [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7448)).

**Workaround**

Since the map is internally saved on the class level, the only working solution was to restart the server. Eventually I've developed a dirty solution, which clears the internal map from zombie elements. Following code is running in a separate thread:

```
public void rehashClickSegmentsIfNecessary() {
    ManagedConcurrentMap instanceMap = lookupInstanceMap(Click.class, "_cassandra_cluster_")
    if(instanceMap.fullSize() - instanceMap.size() > 50000) {
        //we have more than 50 000 zombie references in map
        rehashSegments(instanceMap)
    }
}

private void rehashSegments(ManagedConcurrentMap instanceMap) {
    org.codehaus.groovy.util.ManagedConcurrentMap.Segment[] segments = instanceMap.segments
    for(int i=0;i<segments.length;i++) {
        segments[i].lock()
        try {
            segments[i].rehash()
        } finally {
            segments[i].unlock()
        }
    }
}

private ManagedConcurrentMap lookupInstanceMap(Class clazz, String prop) {
    MetaClassRegistry registry = GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry
    MetaClassImpl metaClass = registry.getMetaClass(clazz)
    return metaClass.getMetaProperty(prop, false).instance2Prop
}
```

Do you have any production experience with cassandra-orm or any other grails plugin connecting to cassandra?